# Removing "constants" from my code so they can be updated

Tags: asp.net

Version : Asp.net 4.5

I have around 500 application constants in my business layer and using it on the presentation layer. Sometime my client wanted to change the values of constants and am in the position to do the dll deployment. But i need to avoid this sort of change. So what is the best choice of maintaining the constants?

I browsed through and found couple of ways. Some of them are suggesting storing it in database and bringing it on the front end and keep it in cache and use it where ever required. in this case if do change the value in database i need to refresh the cache to get the most recent data on the presentation layer.

Some of them are saying, having the constants in separate configuration file and refer the file in web.config file. On this case if we do change any constant value then it will restart the app domain. How do i achieve this. any suggestions please.

How do i achieve in better way

My server is web farm and sticky session used. Any help please

Comment: It sounds like this data is anything but constant - if you have a single system, it sounds like you want to look at patterns around [multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) to allow per-customer configuration. Database sounds about right.

Comment: 1) Come up with a better question title. 2) Don't include tags in the question content, use tags properly.